# Adding a reference to a class library or service from a smart device project in VS.Net?

Tags: visual-studio, reference, wcf

We're trying to debug a WCF service that is being consumed by a smart device project.

The problem is that the service never gets debugged, only stepped over.

Similarly, when trying to add a class library to a smart device project, the following error is seen:

**Cannot add a reference to a desktop project from a smart device project.**

Any tips on how to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am by no means an expert on this, but I would assume that you can't just add references because smart devices have limited resources and you sort of have to work with what you've been given to work with.

Comment: We're using a smart device emulator.  So how do you go about debugging  the service in that case?